# How to filter Tag keys using aws boto3 starting with 'aws:' in ec2.describe_tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

We are using following python code to get all the tags associated to a ebs volume and transfer them back to the snapshots associated with that ebs volume. And we want to exclude aws: reserved tags from the output so that we can just apply them directly as it is.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
volume_tags = ec2.describe_tags(Filters=[{'Name': 'resource-id', 'Values': ['volume-id',],},],)
tag_snapshot = ec2.create_tags(Resources=[snapshot-id],Tags=volume_tags)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. In `describe_tags`, you want to exclude reserved tags?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Yes from describe_tags actions I am trying to exclude aws reserved tags for example.. 

"aws:cloudformation:stack-id"

Comment: there is no further logic/regex filter build inside `describe_tags`. However, you can pass the result to `paginators` and do more complicated filtering there. http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/paginators.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'jq' program with aws cli to filter json results as below

```
aws ec2 describe-tags | jq '.Tags[] | select(contains({Key: "aws:"}) | not)'
```

Possibly use subprocess to execute the above command from python

Unfortunately I'm unable to try the same using python bindings for jq.

jq or pyjq python bindings have installation issues using pip for me